# Mapping a DTO in a DTO to entity in entity with mapstruct

Tags: jhipster, mapstruct

I have a situation where I have another DTO in inside a DTO to which I have to map to its corresponding entity.

I am using mapstruct and I already have AnotherEntityMapper already existing.

```
DTO

public class EntityDTO {

   private AnotherEntityDTO anotherEntityDTO;
   // other fields
}
```

---

```
Entity

@Entity
public class Entity {
  private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
  // other fields
}
```

How to change the EntityMapper interface, so that I can map anotherEntityDTO to anotherEntity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends which version of MapStruct you are using. If you are using 1.2.0.Beta or higher they you can just define the nested properties on your `EntityMapper` interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "anotherEntity", source = "anotherEntityDTO")
    @Mapping(target = "anotherEntity.propE", source = "anotherEntityDTO.propD")
    Entity map(EntityDDTO dto);

}
```

Another option (and a must if you are using version less than 1.2.0.Beta) is to add a new Method in your `EntityMapper` like:

```
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "anotherEntity", source = "anotherEntityDTO")
    Entity map(EntityDDTO dto);

    @Mapping(target = "propE", source = "propD")
    AnotherEntity map(AnotherEntityDTO);
}
```

or you can define a new Mapper `AnotherEntityMapper` for the `AnotherEntity` and use [`@Mapper(uses = {AnotherEntityMapper.class})`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html#uses--):

```
@Mapper
public interface AnotherEntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "propE", source = "propD")
    AnotherEntity map(AnotherEntityDTO);
}

@Mapper(uses = {AnotherEntityMapper.class}
public interface EntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "anotherEntity", source = "anotherEntityDTO")
    Entity map(EntityDDTO dto);
}
```

It really depends on your use case. If you need to do mappings between `AnotherEntity` and `AnotherEntityDTO` on other places, I would suggest to use a new interface so you can reuse it where you need it